# Why 'new WebSocket()' doesn't work for nestjs?

Tags: javascript, websocket, nestjs

I am sending with `const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000'); socket.send('hello world');` from client and i receive log 'connected' log on the server but not 'hello world'. socket.send() not working for NestJS. When I look at chrome network. It sends the data but not receiving in server.
here is the code: **chat.gateway.ts**

```
@WebSocketGateway()
export class ChatGateway implements OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect, OnGatewayInit {
  handleConnection(client: any, ...args: any[]): any {
    console.log('connected');
  }

  handleDisconnect(client: any): any {
    console.log(client);
    console.log('disconnected');
  }

  @SubscribeMessage('message')
  handleEvent(client: any, data: any): WsResponse<any> {
    const event = 'events';
    return { event, data };
  }

  afterInit(server: any): any {
    console.log(server.path);
  }
}
```

**main.ts**

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { WsAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-ws';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
    credentials: true,
  });
  app.useWebSocketAdapter(new WsAdapter(app));
  await app.listen(3000);
}

bootstrap();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the Github examples: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/sample/16-gateways-ws

On the client side:

```js
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:80');
socket.onopen = () => {
  console.log('Connected');
  socket.send(
    JSON.stringify({
      event: 'message',
      data: 'my very important message',
    }),
  );
  socket.onmessage = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };
};
```

This should do the trick